# Default Page redirects to Login - MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I'm having a problem with my project:

Whenever I access to my default page without the controller/action values, it redirects me to the loginUrl
But if I explicitly pass the controller/action, it doesn´t
This is exactly the problem:

If i use the following link, it takes me to the login page:

```
http://mydomain/
```

But if I use this, it works just fine:

```
http://mydomain/Home/Index
```

Here is my Route code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapNavigationRoute<Controllers.HomeController>("Acerca de", a => a.About());

    routes.MapNavigationRoute<Areas.Admin.Controllers.HomeController>("Admninistración", a => a.Index())
        .AddChildRoute<Areas.Admin.Controllers.CompetidoresController>("Competidores", c => c.Index());

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new[] { "HarkDev.Apuestas.Web.Controllers" }
    );

}
```

And my web.config authentication:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

My Home controller has the [Authorize] attribute, but my Index action has the [AllowAnonymous] attribute.

Comment: Try looking where it is trying to go in Firebug. You should be able to see in the NET Tab what URL it is trying to get too before it redirects you. I would guess that Chris's answer below is correct that your default root is not what you think it is!

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to say without being able to see your entire RouteConfig.cs, but the behavior you describe is simply not possible *unless* the default route is not what you think it is. In other words, going to `http://mydomain/` is not actually hitting `HomeController.Index`, but some other controller/action combo that *does* require authentication.

Two things to keep in mind:

1. Just because you name the route "Default", doesn't mean it actually is. The route name doesn't matter for this purpose.
2. MVC Routes short-circuit. In other words, the first matching route MVC sees wins. As a result, you need to be careful about the ordering of routes in RouteConfig.cs, and also ensure that you don't have multiple routes that can match a given url pattern.

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Foo",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Foo", action = "Bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Here, a request for `http://domain.com/` will hit `FooController.Bar`, *not* `HomeController.Index`.

Comment: I'm going to edit and put my entire Route config.
Also, i have a classs callesd AdminAreaRegistration that registers another area.
I have that on my global asax, which I'm going to edit an put on my original question...

Comment: I finally figured Out.
Your answer was the clue.
On my routes file I only had one register (The default) But VIsual Studio, created a class called AdminAreaRegistration when I added an Area called Admin.

This was being called first on my Global.asax.cs file, BEFORE the RegisterAllRoutes.

So, as you said, the order was the problem.

If you'd like, could you edit your answer to also take into account the case where the area registration could be on the global.asax file so that i can mark it as solved?

Thanks!